# Unable to load Android Mapview activity both on emulator and on device

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to load mapview on my emulator and device

I have been trying this for two days but some time I just get grid line without any map, and sometimes a FATAL error and my app doesn't start both on my emulator and device.

I tried everything, every code that is present on internet but nothing works.
You are my last hope.

I followed steps stated on [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key)

I got my API key from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup.html)

I have done everything that I could. Please tell me if this process is not right then what should I do. I am doing it for Gingerbread 2.3.3 (API 10)..

Waiting for the answer thanku.

My Log Cat:
07-06 02:12:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(3020): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

My AndroidMenifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
        Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" /> 

<application   
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAI5QAuDgiTRjyU-y_MK-ZRQqBaN_VoLb4gADuCwA"/>
</application>
```

My Main.xml

```
 <fragment
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
```

My MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.maps;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: just ooi, why not `targetSdk` 17?

Answer (score 0):

In main.xml

Shouldn't

`android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

be

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this didn't work.
the error it gave when i replaced 'name' by 'class' = Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'class' in package 'android'.

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz updated my answer, I had put the namespace in mistakendly

Comment: which support package should i download

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using a fragment but load it in a MapView. This is why you get the RuntimeException, because it is not possible to inflate a fragment into a MapView object. MapView is an old class that was supported in android maps API version 1, which is deprecated now.

From the dev site you quoted:

> Note: The Google Maps Android API v2 uses a new system of managing keys. Existing keys from a Google Maps Android v1 application, commonly known as MapView, will not work with the v2 API.

Your activity should actually extend MapFragment and you should use the FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager to inflate your map.

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
   private GoogleMap mMapView;
   private SupportMapFragment mFragment;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     mFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map));
     mMapView = mFragment.getMap();
     mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
     // configure other settings of map view
   }
}
```

Also the name of the class in the layout xml should also be SupportMapFragment like so:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  tools:context=".MainActivity" 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
```

you can find more info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

Comment: After even extending FragmentActivity, it shows that there isn't any class named GoogleMap or SupportMapFragment

Comment: you have to add the support jar. Read through the guide. It is explained really well and it works: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code

Comment: can you please tell me that from where can i download this support.jar